# Creating a new array from .map() items with certain value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React app, I have an array of key value pairs. Each pair corresponds to a checkbox, so when the checkbox is checked, the value of that key changes to either `true` or `false`. The data that i am pulling from is structured like:

```
filters: {
  categories: [
    {
      name: "Books",
      slug: "books",
      selected: 0,
      data: [
        { checked: false, value: "Fiction", label: "Fiction" },
        { checked: false, value: "NonFiction", label: "NonFiction" },
        { checked: false, value: "Biography", label: "Biography" },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Movies",
      slug: "movies",
      selected: 0,
      data: [
        { checked: false, value: "SciFi", label: "SciFi" },
        { checked: false, value: "Comedy", label: "Comedy" },
        { checked: false, value: "Romance", label: "Romance" },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Music",
      slug: "music",
      selected: 0,
      data: [
        { checked: false, value: "Pop", label: "Pop" },
        { checked: false, value: "Rock", label: "Rock" },
        { checked: false, value: "Alt", label: "Alt" },
      ],
    },
  ],
  selected: 0,
},
```

And I am displaying a simple list on the front-end like:

```
{state.theme.filters.categories.map((filter, id) => {
  return (
    <>
      {filter.data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <p>{item.value}: {item.checked === true ? <span>True</span> : <span>False</span>}</p>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
})}
```

What I am trying to do is create a new array that will automatically update and return only items that are checked true.

Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is posible.

You need to filter the array.

```
{state.theme.filters.categories.map((filter, id) => {
  return (
    <>
      {filter.data.filter(item => item.checked).map((item) => {
        return (
          <p>{item.value}: {item.checked === true ? <span>True</span> : <span>False</span>}</p>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
})}
```

Comment: how would those checked items be put into a new array?

Comment: just do const newArr = filter.data.filter(item => item.checked) because filter method returns a new array

Comment: it looks like that creates a new array for each category. i'm looking for one new array, that will contain all of the categories

Comment: Try const newArr = state.theme.filters.categories.flatMap(category => category.data).filter(item => item.checked)

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want to check the `checked` value before returning, and not return otherwise. Something like this:

```
filter.data.map((item) => {
  if (item.checked === true) {
    return (
      <p>{item.value}</p>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: how would those checked items be put into a new array?